# How can I troubleshoot apps which won't quit and force me to reboot?

Tags: macbook-pro, reboot

I've been having this problem a lot and it's becoming extremely irritating.

So, I force quit an app (mostly Chrome, Steam and uTorrent) that isn't responding and open it again (this is also the situation when I force quit an app that is bouncing and won't open), it bounces for a long time again, so I force quit again, it keeps bouncing for a while and then 'quits'.

But, you can't open it, and when you right click it, it has the same options it would have if it were open. It appears in the force quit menu, but won't quit. It doesn't appear in activity monitor anywhere. Now, I know an obvious solution is to hardware shutdown, but my macbook pro is under a monitor stand and I would have to move a lot of hardware every time it happens.

Comment: is this one specific application (and if yes, which one) or several? Once you force quit the application, does it still show up in Activity Monitor (if yes, please add a screenshot)?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting it. Just go to the Apple menu on the top left of the screen and select Restart. This will shut it down *and* **automatically** start it up again. A restart will likely solve your problem.

Comment: Just attempted, it just stays on the desktop and doesn't end up restarting, I've also attempted shutting it down, but that won't work either.

Comment: @Louienstuff Have you tried repairing disk permissions?

Comment: Just tried, no difference.

Comment: @Louienstuff You might just have to do a hardware shutdown by pressing the power button of your MacBook Pro.

Comment: @Louienstuff You won't believe this, but my Mac just did the SAME EXACT THING that yours was doing. My solution was just to turn it off using the power button and turn it back on again the same way. I can't guarantee that you won't lose any unsaved data that way, though.